# Chrome & Firefox could not load the video file on the wordpress site

Tags: php, wordpress, google-chrome, firefox, video

I have a wordpress site, where users can log in there and watch films uploaded by me (administrator) in the dashboard. Videos are long and there are a large files. 
Unfortunately they do not load on chrome and firefox. Site displays only the controls of the video, but it looks like they are disabled.

[image]

Here is the code with my videos:

```
<video id="trainingVideo<?php echo $tb; ?>" class="training-video embed-responsive-item"  autoplay="autoplay" controls="controls">
     <source src="<?php echo $video_url; ?>" type="<?php echo $video['mime_type'] ?>">
</video>
```

Here is the debug console:

```
jquery-migrate.min.js:2 JQMIGRATE: Migrate is installed, version 1.4.1
/wp-content/uploads/CKZ-Informacje-o-szkoleniu.mp4 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 (Forbidden)
/wp-content/uploads/CKZ-prawo-cywilne.mp4 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 (Forbidden)
/wp-content/uploads/CKZ-prawo-handlowe.mp4 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 (Forbidden)
/wp-content/uploads/CKZ-podatki-op%C5%82aty-i-ubezpieczenia.mp4 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 (Forbidden)
/wp-content/uploads/CKZ-organizacja-i-zarz%C4%85dzanie-przedsi%C4%99biorstwem.mp4 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 508 (unused)
/wp-content/uploads/CKZ-prawo-transportowe.mp4 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 508 (unused)
/wp-content/uploads/CKZ-finansowanie-inwestycji-i-przedsi%C4%99biorstw.mp4 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 (Forbidden)
/wp-content/uploads/CKZ-czas-pracy-kierowc%C3%B3w.mp4 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 (Forbidden)
/wp-content/uploads/CKZ-bezpiecze%C5%84stwo-w-transporcie.mp4 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 (Forbidden)
/wp-content/uploads/CKZ-przewozy-specjalistyczne.mp4 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 (Forbidden)
/wp-content/uploads/CKZ-kontrole-w-transporcie-drogowym.mp4 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 508 (unused)
/wp-content/uploads/CKZ-porozumienia-i-organizacje-w-transporcie-drogowym.mp4 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 508 (unused)
/wp-content/uploads/CKZ-zadania-egzaminacyjne-film.mp4 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 508 (unused)
/wp-content/uploads/CKZ-finanse-i-ksi%C4%99gowo%C5%9B%C4%87.mp4 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
/wp-content/uploads/CKZ-zasady-za%C5%82adunku-pojazd%C3%B3w.mp4 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
/wp-content/uploads/CKZ-prawo-pracy.mp4 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
```

Microsoft edge does not display any error. Could you please help me with this ?

Answer (score 0):

you need to add 2 different source file to play the video.

1st one is mp4

2nd one is ogg

after that the structure will be

```
<video id="trainingVideo<?php echo $tb; ?>" class="training-video embed-responsive-item"  autoplay="autoplay" controls="controls">
    <source src="<?php echo $video_url_mp4; ?>">  <!-- mp4 -->
    <source src="<?php echo $video_url_ogg; ?>"> <!-- ogg -->
</video>
```

Comment: Thanks, but another problem occured. I have now the error **Sorry for the sake of security this file type is not allowed** while I am trying to upload the **OGG** file

Comment: Ok I have upload the OGG file already but there is still the error in console:

`wp-content/uploads/SampleVideo_1280x720_1mb-1.ogg net::ERR_ABORTED`

Comment: are you getting this error in wordpress media upload?

Comment: I have already upload the files without error. Error occur later when I would like to watch the video as a logged user. Video works well on Microsoft Edge only.

Comment: can you please provide the link of website so i can understand it better

Comment: Here is the [website](http://edutrans.pl/e-learning-certyfikat-kompetencji-zawodowych/).

Comment: I am unable to see any video tag on this page

Comment: try now. Sorry about that.

Comment: I think your video is currupted  this is not playing  directlu in browser
Request URL:http://edutrans.pl/wp-content/uploads/CKZ-kontrole-w-transporcie-drogowym.mp4
Request Method:GET
Status Code:404 Not Found
Remote Address:46.41.144.47:80
Referrer Policy:no-referrer-when-downgrade